# Accessing information - Array of pointers

Tags: c

```
int* a[2];
int x = 5;
int y = 7;
int *b = x;
int *c = y;
a[0] = b;
a[1] = c;
printf("%d", *a[1]);
```

Why isn't this working?
This is an Array of pointers and I'm trying to get the value of y - a[1] is the address of y so I added a * to get the value of it..
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please read the warnings that your compiler should be giving you: https://godbolt.org/z/e41f5oehz

Answer (score 1):

```
int *b = x;
int *c = y;
```

The problem here is that your are assigning the values of the objects `x` and `y` instead of their address.

You can get the address of an object using the address-of operator `&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *b = x;
int *c = y;
```

> Why isn't this working?

Because you assign the value held by the integer to the pointer, not the reference of the variable `x` or `y`

You need to:

```
int *b = &x;
int *c = &y;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight change to your code to pass the address of the integer x and y to pointers b and c will make your code work.

```
int *b = &x;
int *c = &y;
```